# how to customize TestNG report result with json format

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I am working with TestNG and selenium webdriver java. I want to make a output report in json format, can testng make a report with json format?Please suggest me a example for this issue.

Comment: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1435

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own reporter that will produce test execution reports in whatever format you need. Here is an example of simple json reporter

```
package test;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.testng.IReporter;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

public class Reporter implements IReporter {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
        JSONArray results = new JSONArray();
        suites.forEach(element->{
            results.add(createSuiteJsonObject(element));
        });
        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(outputDirectory + "/report.json")) {
            file.write(results.toJSONString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public JSONObject createSuiteJsonObject(ISuite suite) {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray passedMethods = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray failedMethods = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray skippedMethods = new JSONArray();
        suite.getResults().entrySet().forEach(element -> {
            ITestContext context = element.getValue().getTestContext();
            passedMethods.addAll(createResultJsonArray(context.getPassedTests().getAllResults()));
            failedMethods.addAll(createResultJsonArray(context.getFailedTests().getAllResults()));
            skippedMethods.addAll(createResultJsonArray(context.getSkippedTests().getAllResults()));
        });
        result.put("name", suite.getName());
        result.put("passed", passedMethods);
        result.put("failed", failedMethods);
        result.put("skipped", skippedMethods);
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public JSONArray createResultJsonArray(Set<ITestResult> results) {
        JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
        results.forEach(element ->{
            JSONObject currentJsonResult = new JSONObject();
            currentJsonResult.put("name", element.getName());
            result.add(currentJsonResult);
        });
        return result;
    }


}
```

And example of the report produced by it

```
[
    {
        "name": "Suite1",
        "passed": [
            {
                "name": "test1"
            }
        ],
        "failed": [
            {
                "name": "test2"
            },
            {
                "name": "test3"
            }
        ],
        "skipped": [
            {
                "name": "test4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```