# How to convert XML report to JSON report for TestNG Java

Tags: java, json, testng, report, testng.xml

I am trying to find a solution for converting XML report to JSON report in TestNG and Selenium Webdriver Java. The XML is stored in the test-output folder. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291621/how-to-customize-testng-report-result-with-json-format 
Maybe helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to customize TestNG report result with json format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291621/how-to-customize-testng-report-result-with-json-format)